# CSV Parser through angularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, node.js, data-manipulation

I am building a CSV file parser through node and Angular . so basically a user upload a csv file , on my server side which is node the csv file is traversed and parsed using [node-csv](https://www.npmjs.org/package/csv-parse) 
. This works fine and it returns me an array of object based on csv file given as input , Now on angular end I need to display two table one is csv file data itself and another is [cross tabulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_tabulation) analysis. I am facing problem while rendering data, so for a table like

[image]

I am getting parse responce as

[image]

For cross tabulation we need data in a tabular form as

[image]

I have a object array which I need to manipulate in best possible way so as to make easily render on html page . I am not getting a way how to do calculation on data I get so as to store cross tabulation result .Any idea on how should I approach .

data json is  :

```
[{"Sample #":"1","Gender":"Female","Handedness;":"Right-handed;"},{"Sample #":"2","Gender":"Male","Handedness;":"Left-handed;"},{"Sample #":"3","Gender":"Female","Handedness;":"Right-handed;"},{"Sample #":"4","Gender":"Male","Handedness;":"Right-handed;"},{"Sample #":"5","Gender":"Male","Handedness;":"Left-handed;"},{"Sample #":"6","Gender":"Male","Handedness;":"Right-handed;"},{"Sample #":"7","Gender":"Female","Handedness;":"Right-handed;"},{"Sample #":"8","Gender":"Female","Handedness;":"Left-handed;"},{"Sample #":"9","Gender":"Male","Handedness;":"Right-handed;"},{"Sample #":";"}
```

Comment: Please **a)** make the parsed data available in literal form, to experiment with, not as a screenshot; and **b)** fix the awkward output (`Handedness;` as a key, `Right-handed;` as a value, `Sample #` as a key?)

Comment: @yerforkferchips : added real json object also , keys are awkward bcoz those key are from csv file itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways you can do this and since you have not been very specific on the usage, I will go with the simplest one.

Assuming you have an object structure such as this:

```
[
{gender: 'female', handdness: 'lefthanded', id: 1},
{gender: 'male', handdness: 'lefthanded', id: 2},
{gender: 'female', handdness: 'righthanded', id: 3},
{gender: 'female', handdness: 'lefthanded', id: 4},
{gender: 'female', handdness: 'righthanded', id: 5}
]
```

and in your controller you have exposed this with something like:

```
$scope.members = [the above array of objects];
```

and you want to display the total of female members of this object, you could filter this in your html

```
 {{(members | filter:{gender:'female'}).length}}
```

Now, if you are going to make this a table it will obviously make some ugly and unreadable html so especially if you are going to repeat using this, it would be a good case for making a directive and repeat it anywhere, with the prerequisite of providing a scope object named tabData (or whatever you wish) in your parent scope

```
.directive('tabbed', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<table><tr><td>{{(tabData | filter:{gender:"female"}).length}}</td></tr><td>{{(tabData | filter:{handedness:"lefthanded"}).length}}</td></table>'
  }
});
```

You would use this in your html like so:

```
 <tabbed></tabbed>
```

And there are ofcourse many ways to improve this as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a general data structure/JS question than Angular related.

[Functional helpers from *Lo-dash*](https://lodash.com/docs) come in very handy here:

```
_(data) // Create a chainable object from the data to execute functions with
.groupBy('Gender') // Group the data by its `Gender` attribute
// map these groups, using `mapValues` so the named `Gender` keys persist
.mapValues(function(gender) {
  // Create named count objects for all handednesses
  var counts = _.countBy(gender, 'Handedness');
  // Calculate the total of all handednesses by summing
  // all the values of this named object
  counts.Total = _(counts)
    .values()
    .reduce(function(sum, num) { return sum + num });
  // Return this named count object -- this is what each gender will map to
  return counts;
}).value(); // get the value of the chain
```

No need to worry about for-loops or anything of the sort, and this code also works without any changes for more than two genders (even for more than two handednesses - think of the aliens and the ambidextrous). If you aren't sure exactly what's happening, it should be easy enough to pick apart the single steps and their result values of this code example.

Calculating the total row for all genders will work in a similar manner.

Comment: hey thank you so much , the solution seems to be working correctly , but the csv file may be containing attribute with different name say gander(male/female) and eatingHabbits(veg/non-veg). In that case I can not specify the   .groupBy and then _.countBy attribtue any suggestion for makin it genric :)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you're saying, but I feel like that is a different problem that is not related to the original question itself. If this answered your original question, please mark it as accepted. Thanks!

Comment: If you need any help on how to expand on this, just read the lo-dash docs, they are concise and easy to understand.